# How to schedule the refresh of a Power BI Report

Tags: powerbi

My dataset is in Azure Analysis Services and I would like to schedule my Power BI report to refresh every hour but the option is blocked. Is this happening because my dataset is in the cloud and it is already being automatically refreshed?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are connecting to AAS, you normally connect via Live Connection, so there is no need to schedule a refresh. When the report loads it will use the latest data that is in the cube. The refresh should be handled via the cube, using for example an Azure Data Factory step, that processes the cube once the underlying database is updated.

For more details on Live Connections see the MS Docs website https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-analysis-services-tabular-data